# Where did the griffins go in Phaze?

Tags: magic, magical-creatures, piers-anthony

In the Apprentice Adept series, book 1, Split Infinity, chapter 14, when Stile is attempting to escape from the Yellow Adept we read this.

> There were cages all around. It resembled an archaic zoo. Stile identified a griffin, with the body of a lion and head and wings of an eagle...

Then, in chapter 1 of Unicorn Point, we see Mach disguised as a griffon, and Stile running from him.

> “Griffin!” he exclaimed. “That’s a griffin! Head and wings of an eagle, body of a lion!”
>
> Neysa made a musical toot of agreement and continued running at speed. She had known it by the sound and smell.  “But there are no griffins in Phaze!” he exclaimed after a moment.
>
> Yet there it was, and gaining on them. A classic heraldic monster. Obviously it did exist here.

Where did the disconnect happen? Is there some passage somewhere where they become extinct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just one of those cases where the author made a mistake and forgot the reference to griffins earlier in the series.

That said, if you want to retcon a fix to this error, you can presume that all the griffins in Phaze were killed during the events at the end of JUXTAPOSITION.